# Android listview how to implement onscrollchanged and onscroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which will be populated more than 3000 items at a time. Each item has an imageview whose image I have to fetch from server. I want that when user scrolls and finish completes, listview load images of only those views which are visible on screen and also deletes  images of those rows which has been scrolled up and down (not visible) on screen so that their images can be redownloaded when they get come on screen because I cannot keep images of all data due to memory limitations.

Comment: It's not simple, but [this can](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) help.

Answer (score 0):

ListView already reuses views that are not visible, so no need to delete them afterwards, but you could optimize this by adding an scroll listener to the list and don't download images when the user is flinging, only when the scroll is stopping.